# The matrix doesn't print correctly

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to display a matrix `3xn`, `n` being determined by the lenghth of a phrase introduce.
The problem itself is that instead of displaying a `3x2` matrix for abcdef it like this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0lMu.png)

I used the standard way for printing it with a `for` for the rows and another one inside for the colums:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < v1idk.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < v1idk.length; j++) {
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(v1idk[i])
                + Arrays.toString(v1idk[j]));
    }
```

`v1idk` being a `int` variable. Does it has to do anything with the `System.err.println`, or does there's no problem in this bit and I should search in other place?

If it was necessary here is the rest of the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItLOU.png)

Comment: Very similar to https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode ... your console output is pure text, too. So please provide it as text, not screenshot. And your description doesnt make sense. v1idk is definitely NOT an int, but an array of array of int. very much different.

Comment: And hint: research how multi-dim arrays in Java work. Meaning: you have an array of arrays here, that is why it makes a difference whether you use one index or TWO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `Arrays.toString(v1idk[i])` denotes the Ith row of the matrix as string and `Arrays.toString(v1idk[j])` denotes the Jth row of the matirx as string.

Let's say `v1idk = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`. Here `v1idk[0]` is `{1, 2}` and `v1idk[1]` is `{3, 4}` and so on.

I hope your problem is clear now.

I think your problem can be solved this way:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < v1idk.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < v1idk[0].length; j++) {
        System.err.println(v1idk[i][j]);
    }
}

//Output is 123456
```

If you want to add spaces and view different rows on different lines, follow this code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < v1idk.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < v1idk[0].length; j++) {
        //Adding space between consecutive elements
        System.err.println(v1idk[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(); //adds new line after each row
}

//Output is 123456
```

Here, `v1idk.length` denotes the number of rows and `v1idk[0].length` denotes the length of each column.